I would like to ask for help regarding the issuance of TON NFT
I mint an NFT. In the NFT item contract I can see it's initialized and returns the content and it's not empty. However, neither wallet nor tonviewer show any of the metadata that I've provided. What am I missing?
Here is the code about constructing metadata:
export function setItemContentCell_nft(content: itemContent): Cell {
    console.log("content content content",content.image);
    
    const itemContentDict = Dictionary.empty(Dictionary.Keys.BigUint(256), Dictionary.Values.Cell())
    .set(toSha256("name"), toTextCell1(content.name))
    .set(toSha256("description"), toTextCell1(content.description))
    .set(toSha256("image"), toTextCell1(content.image)) 
     
    return beginCell()
            .storeUint(0,8)
            .storeDict(itemContentDict)
            .endCell();
}


Please [edit] the title of your question to be descriptive, unambiguous, and specific to what you are asking. For more guidance, see How do I write a good title?.

Please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly define the problem that you are trying to solve. Additional details — including all relevant code, error messages, and debugging logs — will help readers to better understand your problem and [what you are asking].

So how exactly do you use setItemContentCell_nft? Without seeing the rest of the script, it's impossible to say what went wrong, maybe you've just constructed the Cell but haven't passed it further
